# Does GCC statically estimate code execution time during optimizations?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I'm trying the `-fopt-info` option of `gcc` to print the optimizations applied.

For the following example code (`src.c`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int op(int x) {
    if (x >= 0) {
        return (x + 1) * (x + 2) / 2;
    } else {
        return -x;
    }
}

int f(int x) {
    int r = 0;
    int v[10] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        r += op(v[i]);
    }
    return r;
}

int main(void) {
    int x;
    int r = scanf("%d", &x);
    return f(x) % 2 + r;
}
```

complied using `gcc -O3 -fopt-info src.c` (GCC version 9.4.0), it prints

```
src.c:15:8: optimized:  Inlining op/23 into f/24.
src.c:23:9: optimized:  Inlining f/24 into main/25.
optimized:  Inlined op.part.0.constprop/31 into main/25 which now has time 59.004400 and size 13, net change of -3.
optimized:  Inlined op.part.0.constprop/30 into f/24 which now has time 44.004400 and size 7, net change of -6.
optimized:  Inlined op.part.0/32 into op/23 which now has time 6.770000 and size 10, net change of +1.
src.c:14:2: optimized: loop with 10 iterations completely unrolled (header execution count 97603136)
src.c:14:2: optimized: loop with 10 iterations completely unrolled (header execution count 97603136)
```

I'm wondering what those "time", "size", and "header execution count" mean. It looks that GCC is trying to estimate the execution cost of the code? I'm wondering how GCC does this.

I didn't find any relevant document. This doesn't look like the "profile-guided optimization". Also, since the input is not fixed (`scanf("%d", &x)`) and running the above compilation multiple times gives the same "times", those numbers shouldn't be any dynamic execution cost. So does GCC use some cost model to estimate the execution time in compilation time?

Comment: The source code containing these output message "which now has time" is gcc/ipa-inline.cc.